# Time in datatime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time, sql-convert

I have a field that stores the date and time but need to extract this so it only shows the time but shows the date as `01/01/1900`.

I can extract the time using the below but need to include the data of `01/01/1900`

```
convert(varchar(12), w.created, 114)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: 01/01/1900 is the epoch used by Excel. You're not, by any chance, trying to get the value so Excel can show it as a time?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, then you can do:

```
select cast('1900-01-01' as datetime) + cast(cast(w.created as time) as datetime)
```

This returns the value as a `datetime`.

SQL Server has a `time` data type.  It is unclear why you would want to add in a fake date, but you can.